# SIM800L and DTH22

Tags: arduino-uno

I am very new to arduino. I am build a model that will require SIM800L and DTH22. I want to know if I can power both from my arduino. DTH22 has a wide range of input voltage but I doubt of SIM800L. It says 3.4V-4.4V but one arduino forum said that it requires 2Amps of current. But many people simply connect it to arduino 3.3V. Can anyone with experience tell me about this? (I am asking as I fried the microcontroller in my previous project.) Should I get externel power supply or go forward with arduino?

Comment: What does the documentation with your SIM800L module say about how it should be powered? The [Data Sheet](https://img.filipeflop.com/files/download/Datasheet_SIM800L.pdf) states a maximum current of 2.0A during Tx burst and 200-450 mA in other modes. I would not recommend using the Arduino internal power supply. The DHT22 uses almost no power at all and can be easily powered from the Arduino.

Answer (score 2):

**Do not connect any GSM module to an Arduino board 3.3v**

This SimCom GSM modules like sim800L or sim800C can take burst current of 2Amp in low network area to provide proper network and another thing is that below 3.4v and above 4.4v it will shut down automatically and you will get an Undervoltage & overvoltage warning AT response on UART before shutdown.

Another thing is that the 3.3v voltage regulator on the Arduino board can only handle up to 1Amp max and above 500ma consumption its temperature will rise and near 1A even more.

So the conclusion don't provide supply to sim800l from Arduino.